# Using partials when building custom generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am building custom generators to generate rails models. The generator can use one of many templates to build one model. Some logic is the same in all templates.

Is it possible to extract some parts of the templates into partials?

Here's an example of what I want to do:

`lib/generators/custom_model/custom_model_generator.rb`

```
class CustomModelGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
  argument :model_name, type: :string
  argument :model_type, type: :string
  ...

  include GeneratorsHelper

  def generate_model
    template_path =
      case model_type
      when 'car' then 'car_model.rb.erb'
      when 'plane' then 'plane_model.rb.erb'
      ...
      end

    template template_path, "app/models/#{model_name}.rb"
  end
end
```

Here is one template:

`lib/generators/custom_model/templates/car_model.rb.erb`

```
class <%= model_name.camelcase %> < ApplicationRecord
  def start
    puts "Vroum!"
  end
end
```

The `#start` method will also be used in the other model generators. I would like to extract it it something like a partial. Is that possible?

Comment: Its certainly possible but I don't think there is anything built in. Templates are not rendered by ActionView. You could probably write something like a helper method that calls `template template_path, path_to_partial`.